# Adding an extra column to (big) SQLite database from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I feel like I'm overlooking something really simple, but I can't make it work. I'm using `SQLite` now, but a solution in `SQLAlchemy` would also be very helpful.

Let's create our original dataset:

```
### This is just the setup part
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')

orig = pd.DataFrame({'COLUPC': [100001, 100002, 100003, 100004],
'L5': ['ABC ALE', 'ABC MALT LIQUOR', 'ABITA AMBER', 'ABITA AMBER'],
'attr1': [0.25, 0.25, 0.041, 0.041]})

orig.to_sql("UPCs", conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

#Create an index just in case it's needed
conn.execute("""CREATE INDEX upc_index
ON UPCs (COLUPC);""")
```

Now suppose I take that `orig` `dataframe` and add a column called 'L5_lower'. Then I create the column in the SQLite database:

```
# Create new variable
orig['L5_lower'] = orig.L5.str.lower()
conn.execute("alter table UPCs add column L5_lower TEXT;")
```

Now suppose I want to fill in this single column `L5_lower` to the SQLite table, without having to pass other columns (below I explain why I need this)

I tried passing the index and the new column as tuples:

```
query='''insert or replace into UPCs (COLUPC, L5_lower) values (?,?) '''
conn.executemany(query, orig[['COLUPC', 'L5_lower']].to_records(index=False))
conn.commit() 

# But then:
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM UPCs;", conn)
conn.close()
```

gives this messed up result.

```
    COLUPC                               L5                 attr1   L5_lower
0   100001                               ABC ALE            0.250   None
1   100002                               ABC MALT LIQUOR    0.250   None
2   100003                               ABITA AMBER        0.041   None
3   100004                               ABITA AMBER        0.041   None
4   b'\xa1\x86\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'     None            NaN     abc ale
5   b'\xa2\x86\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'     None            NaN     abc malt liquor
6   b'\xa3\x86\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'     None            NaN     abita amber
7   b'\xa4\x86\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'     None            NaN     abita amber
```

Instead, the expected output is:

```
    COLUPC                               L5                 attr1   L5_lower
0   100001                               ABC ALE            0.250   abc ale
1   100002                               ABC MALT LIQUOR    0.250   abc malt liquor
2   100003                               ABITA AMBER        0.041   abita amber
3   100004                               ABITA AMBER        0.041   abita amber
```

So, why am I trying to pass a single column? I have a very big dataset and I won't be able to have the whole dataframe in memory. My intended workflow is to construct one column at a time and then `update` or `insert` into the SQLite database.

Comment: AFAIK you can't add COLUMNS using Pandas `to_sql` - you can add ROWS. One solution would be to insert a new column into a temporary table (with the same index as the original table has) and then update the source table on the SQLite side...

Comment: @MaxU Could you please provide some example code as an answer? I guess it makes sense to delete the auxiliary table after that.

Comment: I've added [a working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41496157/5741205) - please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you can't add COLUMNS using Pandas to_sql - you can add ROWS. One solution would be to insert a new column into a temporary table (with the same index as the original table has) and then update the source table on the SQLite side.

Here is a working example:

**SETUP:**

assuming we have the following original DF:

```
In [79]: orig
Out[79]:
   COLUPC               L5  attr1
0  100001          ABC ALE  0.250
1  100002  ABC MALT LIQUOR  0.250
2  100003      ABITA AMBER  0.041
3  100004      ABITA AMBER  0.041

In [80]: orig.set_index('COLUPC', inplace=True)

In [81]: conn = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/test.sqlite')

In [82]: orig.to_sql('upcs', conn, if_exists='replace', index=True)

In [83]: conn.close()
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
In [84]: conn = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/test.sqlite')

In [85]: df = pd.read_sql('select * from upcs', conn, index_col='COLUPC')

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
                     L5  attr1
COLUPC
100001          ABC ALE  0.250
100002  ABC MALT LIQUOR  0.250
100003      ABITA AMBER  0.041
100004      ABITA AMBER  0.041
```

create temporary table:

```
In [87]: tmp = orig.L5.str.lower().to_frame('L5_lower')

In [88]: tmp
Out[88]:
               L5_lower
COLUPC
100001          abc ale
100002  abc malt liquor
100003      abita amber
100004      abita amber

In [89]: tmp.to_sql('tmp', conn, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

add new column to SQLite table:

```
In [90]: conn.execute('alter table UPCs add column L5_lower varchar(50)')
Out[90]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa558c00>

In [91]: qry = 'update upcs set L5_lower = (select L5_lower from tmp where tmp.COLUPC = upcs.COLUPC) where L5_lower is NULL'

In [92]: conn.execute(qry)
Out[92]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa593570>

In [93]: conn.commit()

In [94]: conn.execute('drop table tmp')
Out[94]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa5930a0>
```

Check:

```
In [95]: pd.read_sql('select * from upcs', conn, index_col='COLUPC')
Out[95]:
                     L5  attr1         L5_lower
COLUPC
100001          ABC ALE  0.250          abc ale
100002  ABC MALT LIQUOR  0.250  abc malt liquor
100003      ABITA AMBER  0.041      abita amber
100004      ABITA AMBER  0.041      abita amber

In [96]: conn.close()
```

Comment: Great work, thanks! I keep getting surprised how easy it is to add rows, but not columns. In my line of work, I seldom do the first, but continuously do the second

Comment: @cd98, in this case you may want to work with transposed data sets: your columns will become rows or at least store it this way

Comment: If updating several columns, is there a more efficient code than ' set col1 = (select col1 from temp where temp.id = table.id), col2 = (select col2 from temp where temp.id = table.id)' ?

Comment: What is the purpose of 'where L5_lower is NULL' in qry? If my new column also contains NULL value, will that affect the code?