# How to insert a column from a DataFrame into a new column of a database table with variable column count using python

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite

I have a DataFrame with data: (Table 1)

```
column1   column2(variable)
A            2
B            1
C            3
D            5
```

The DataFrame value i.e. column2 name and values change every time the scripts are run. So let us consider on next run, values in dataframe are like this:

```
column1   column2(variable)
A            7
B            8
C            9
D            7
```

I want to add the new(updated column2 values to database table) so that now the database table becomes something like this:

```
column1   column2  column3    
A            2        7
B            1        8
C            3        9
D            5        7
```

I can find many similar questions on stack overflow but non of them seems to solve this, since, here the column count in database table is changing on every run, also in current code scenario, I am unable to create a temporary table and do a transplant as described here:
[Adding an extra column to (big) SQLite database from Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495068/adding-an-extra-column-to-big-sqlite-database-from-pandas-dataframe) .

**My code:**

```
df2 = df.groupby('column1').size().reset_index(name=currentDate)
```

where currentDate has today's date and hence the table has 2 columns now (column1 and currentdate). I want to add this data to already present Table 1(above) in the database without using a new temporary table(keeping in mind that I have to use SQL query with a variable name i.e. currentDate).

Answer (score 0):

Do a `df.iloc[:,-1].name` to get the last column's name that is added in.
You can then add the column via the usual assignment

As per my understanding of your question:
Assuming df is your original table and you are trying to add an additional column to it with the same name as the last column in df2:

```
df[df2.iloc[:,-1].name] = df2.iloc[:,-1]
```

This means that:

```
#Original df
column1   column2
A            2
B            1
C            3
D            5
#Original df2
column1   NEW_NAME
A            7
B            8
C            9
D            7
#New df
column1   column2  NEW_NAME    
A            2        7
B            1        8
C            3        9
D            5        7
```

Comment: that might be helpful but would you please elaborate on how to do that assignment in your answer, since I am a beginner.

Comment: @sudoCoder Show your code in your question. Otherwise, its difficult to make a guess on how my solution will fit into your code. Drop a comment here once you've done so and I can edit my answer to help

Comment: please have a look now, I have updated the question with code snippet.

Comment: Grateful to your efforts, but I think this only gives me the column name, I already have the column name in variable ```currentDate``` , I need a way to add the new column to already present SQLite DB table